# Add some gap in between legend and the chart

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, nvd3.js

In [my fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/vfe2B/51), I want to add some gap in between the legends at the top and the chart, so as to look better.

I tried:

```
d3.select(".nv-linesWrap").style("padding-top","50px");
```

but it didnt work.

How do I fix this?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/vfe2B/51/)

Comment: How is this question off-topic??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at xTicks attributes in line 102.

```
.attr('transform', function(d,i,j) { return 'translate (-10, 40) rotate(-90 0,0)' });
```

There you can translate and rotate your scalevalues.

In your case, just raise the value of the second translate paramater (40->60).

And a tipp:
play around with those attributes, the first rotateparameter to "-45" makes it really better to read, so you dont have to turn your head every time ;)

**//EDIT (Wrong solution)**

the legendwrap has the same function and an equal behaviour of the translate function.
Just insert following in line 110:

```
 d3.select(".nv-legendWrap")
        .style("float", "right")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0,-75)");
```

Maybe you now have to resize your whole SVG Container where the whole chart is placed

**//EDIT2 (Improvement)**

to resize the whole Chart (or margin-top+25) i used the following way: just put this part after your legendWrap.

```
     d3.select(".nv-wrap.nv-lineChart").attr("transform", "translate(100,75)");
```

Comment: Not sure if you get my question correctly. The legends are the indicators/controls at the top.

Comment: oh i'm sorry, i just edited it above with a possible solution.

Comment: That works but its throwing the legends out of the screen. I tried to apply the same idea to the actual chart but it didnt work.

Comment: yes, i saw it. The Edit2 shows you how to margin-top the whole chart

Comment: But like I said in the question, the gap needs to be in between the legend and the chart buddy.

Comment: Where is the problem? Simply adjust the top-values of the translate function. Maybe -90 and 90. There is definitively a bigger gap than before

Comment: The gap is appearing above the legends, thats the problem. It needs to below the legends.

Comment: You have to use both! transform your legendWrap AND your lineChart like its written above!

Comment: Can you please help me with this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24673333/unable-to-plot-chart-with-new-data-format

Comment: I had the same issue as @Rahul Desai. I tried this approach of adding both, legendWrap and lineChart, however for me, though the whole chart was able to push down, when i click on any of the legend circles, to uncheck the circle, the chart comes back to its original position?? is ther any way to resolve that issue?? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can control the distance of the chart legend from chart as follows:

```
chart.legend.margin({
    top: 0,
    bottom: 10,
    left: 0,
    right: 0
});
```

Please modify the top / bottom values as required.

Note that by default nvd3 uses following values: {top: 5, right: 0, bottom: 5, left: 0}

For introducing space between individual legends there is no direct way as this is not controlled by CSS property and is hard-coded within nvd3 itself.

In nvd3 legend.js line 120:

```
seriesWidths.push(nodeTextLength + 128); // 28 is ~ the width of the circle plus some padding
```

You can increase this 28 value to increase space between legends.

Comment: Sorry, that didnt help. I tested it in the fiddle of mine.

Comment: The above method essentially introduces space between legend section and the chart visualization. However you need, if I understand correctly, to increase space between individual legends. Updated my answer for this.

Comment: Tried that. It made no difference. :(